# Ubuntu 22.04 GPU Hang i915 Issue

Tags: kernel, freeze, gpu, i915

My computer (specs at bottom of post) keeps freezing, and sometimes completely locking up needing a hard reset. I have found the error in the syslog, I'll post it below. The issue seems to occur semi randomly, I can't tell what is causing it. So far it's happened 6 times:

1. When editing code in Gedit and using the terminal
2. Same as above (had to hard reset)
3. Same as above
4. In a VirtualBox VM
5. When editing code
6. When editing code and also using a web browser (had to hard reset)

Here is the error: (seems to be same every time so just posting on, I can post them all if needed to a pastebin)

```
Jan 18 11:03:15 usernamelaptop kernel: [180359.703364] Asynchronous wait on fence 0000:00:02.0:gnome-shell[1820]:2f8d4 timed out (hint:intel_atomic_commit_ready [i915])
Jan 18 11:03:19 usernamelaptop kernel: [180363.551062] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 12:0:00000000
Jan 18 11:03:19 usernamelaptop kernel: [180363.551118] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Resetting chip for stopped heartbeat on rcs0
Jan 18 11:03:19 usernamelaptop kernel: [180363.555862] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_62.0.3.bin version 62.0 submission:enabled
Jan 18 11:03:19 usernamelaptop kernel: [180363.555871] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GuC SLPC: enabled
Jan 18 11:03:19 usernamelaptop kernel: [180363.555874] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin version 7.9 authenticated:yes
Jan 18 11:03:19 usernamelaptop gsd-media-keys[2371]: [GFX1-]: GFX: RenderThread detected a device reset in PostUpdate
```

Specs:

Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro 14IAP7
i7-1260P with Integrated Iris Graphics (Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2))
16GB DDR5
512 NVME SSD
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic

Only been using the system with linux for about a month, haven't encountered this issue until a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

In the file `/etc/default/grub` append the parameter `i915.enable_psr=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
Then `sudo update-grub2` and reboot.